# Image processing error

Tags: c++, image-processing, runtime-error

I must implement in C++ using diblok **The Seeded Region Growing algorithm due to Adams and Bischof** which can be found here **http://bit.ly/1nIxphj**. 
It is the fig.2 pseudocode.

After I choose the seeded points using the mouse , it throws this message : **Unhandled exception at 0x00416ca0 in diblook.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x3d2f6e68.**

This is the code of the function:

```
void CDibView::OnLButtonDblClk(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
```

{   BEGIN_SOURCE_PROCESSING;

```
int** labels = new int* [dwHeight];
for(int k = 0;k < dwHeight; k++)
    labels[k] = new int[dwWidth];
int noOfRegions = 2;
double meanRegion[2];
double noOfPointsInRegion[2];
for(int i = 0; i < dwHeight ; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < dwWidth ; j++)
    {
        labels[i][j] = -1;
    }




if(noOfPoints < 6)
{
    CPoint p = GetScrollPosition() + point;
    pos[noOfPoints].x = p.x;
    pos[noOfPoints].y = p.y;
    int regionLabel = 0;
    if(noOfPoints <= noOfPoints / 2)
        labels[p.x][p.y] = regionLabel;
    else 
        labels[p.x][p.y] = regionLabel + 1;
    noOfPoints++;
}
else
{
    // Calculate the mean of each region

    for(int i = 0; i < noOfRegions; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < noOfPoints; j++)
        {
            if(labels[pos[j].x][pos[j].y] == i)
            {
                meanRegion[i] += lpSrc[pos[j].x * w + pos[j].y];
            }
        }
        meanRegion[i] /= 3;
        noOfPointsInRegion[i] = 3;
    }

    for(int seedPoint = 0; seedPoint < noOfPoints; seedPoint++)
    {

        // define list
        node *start, *temp;
        start = (node *) malloc (sizeof(node));
        temp = start;
        temp -> next = NULL;


        for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
            for(int j = -1; j<= 1; j++)
            {
                if(i == 0 && j == 0) continue;
                int gamma = lpSrc[(pos[seedPoint].x + i) *  + pos[seedPoint].y + j] - lpSrc[pos[seedPoint].x * w + pos[seedPoint].y];
                push(start, pos[seedPoint].x + i, pos[seedPoint].y + j, gamma);


            }

        sort(start);

        if(start != NULL)
        {
            node *y = start; 
            pop(start);
            int sameNeighbour = 1;
            int neighValue = -1;
            for(int k = -1; k <= 1; k++)
                for(int l = -1; l <= 1;l++)
                {
                    if(k ==0 && l==0) continue;
                    if(labels[y -> x + k][y -> y + l] != -1)
                    {
                        neighValue = labels[y -> x + k][y -> y + l];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                for(int k = -1; k <= 1; k++)
                    for(int l = -1; l <= 1;l++)
                    {
                        if(k == 0 && l==0) continue;
                        if(labels[y -> x + k][y -> y = 1] != -1 && labels[y -> x + k][y -> y + l] != neighValue)
                            sameNeighbour = 0;
                    }
                    if(sameNeighbour == 1)
                    {
                        labels[y -> x][y -> y] = neighValue;
                        meanRegion[neighValue] = meanRegion[neighValue] * noOfPointsInRegion[neighValue] / noOfPointsInRegion[neighValue] + 1;
                        noOfPointsInRegion[neighValue]++;

                        for(int k = -1; k <= 1; k++)
                            for(int l = -1; l <= 1;l++)
                            {
                                if(k == 0 && l == 0) continue;
                                if(labels[y -> x + k][y -> y + l] == -1 && find(start, y->x + k, y->y + l) == 0)
                                {
                                    int gammak = meanRegion[neighValue] - lpSrc[(y->x +k) * w + (y->y + l)];
                                    push(start, y->x + k, y->y + l, gammak);
                                    sort(start);
                                }
                            }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        labels[y->x][y->y] = -1;
                    }
        }

    }


    int noOfRegionOne = 0;
    int noOfRegionTwo = 0;
    int noOfBoundary = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i< dwHeight; i++)
        for(int j = 0;j<dwWidth; j++)
        {
            if(labels[i][j] == -1)
                noOfBoundary++;
            else if(labels[i][j] == 0)
                noOfRegionOne++;
            else if(labels[i][j] == 1)
                noOfRegionTwo++;
        }

        CString info;
        info.Format("Boundary %d, One %d, Two %d", noOfBoundary, noOfRegionOne, noOfRegionTwo);
        AfxMessageBox(info);

    noOfPoints = 0;
}

CScrollView::OnLButtonDblClk(nFlags, point);


END_SOURCE_PROCESSING;
```

}

After a choose to break the running, this is what is shown **http://postimg.org/image/j2sh9k0a1/**

Can anybody tell what is wrong and why it doesn't work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that your node (Y is a terrible name, incidentally) has garbage values in it.  Offhand, I suspect that 'sort' is overwriting your node values, resulting in garbage.  I would create a static copy of your current node to prevent it from changing during processing:

Change

```
    node *y = start; 
    pop(start);
```

to

```
    node y = *start; 
    pop(start);
```

Comment: So you say that the name Y is wrong? If I modify as you say, it throws a bunch of errors like this:  error C2232: '->Node::y' : left operand has 'struct' type, use '.'

Comment: If you change y to a struct (instead of a pointer), you will need to replace `y->blah` with `y.blah`.  That's the nature of C.

Comment: My comment about the name 'Y' is that you're using 'Y' in other contexts, and having the same name mean two different things is confusing.  If asked, i'd change 'node y' to 'node current'.